# AsyncBridge in .net 4 cannot await Task<string>

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, async-await, async-ctp

I've a .net 4 project where I want to use the async functionality.

So I added the Async .net 4 bridge.

My method is declared as

```
public async Task<string> Foo(string value1, string value2)
```

The consumer calls the message like this

```
private static async void run()
{
    string result = await adapter.Foo();
}
```

but the compiler tells me

> Error 1   Cannot await
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' C:\dev\TestRunner\Program.cs    34  29  TestRunner.

When I switch the project to 4.5 it works
Any hint whats going wrong?

The Foo Method itself contains an await for HttpClient.Get which works.

Here the code of the FOO Method which works:

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  string url = ServerUrl + @"/api/test";    
  var content = getjsonContent();
  var result = await client.PostAsync();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Async Targeting Pack instead?

Comment: +1 to svick's recommendation - you can find details on their update from this week @  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: Using the Async Targeting Pack instead was the solution @svick: Do you want to post this as a reply so I can mark it as the answer?